# How to read a specific element from a binary file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a binary file. If I want to read all the numeric data in an array at once, the code is below:

```
y = Array{Float32}(undef, 1000000, 1);

read!("myfile.bin", y)
```

I will get an array y, y is 1000000*1 array{Float32, 2}.

My question is that, I don't want to read all the data in an array at once since it will use a lot of memory. I want to read a specific element in the binary file each time. For example, I only want to read the third element in the binary file which is the third element in array y. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read a single element, you don't need to read into an array:

```
io = open("myfile.bin", "r") # open file for reading
Nbytes = sizeof(Float32) # number of bytes per element
seek(io, (3-1)*Nbytes) # move to the 3rd element
val = read(io, Float32) # read a Float32 element
close(io)
```

BTW: if you want an array for your data, you should probably use a 1000000 length `Array{Float32, 1}` instead of a size 1000000x1 `Array{Float32, 2}`:

```
y = Array{Float32}(undef, 1000000)
# or
y = Array{Float32, 1}(undef, 1000000)
# or
y = Vector{Float32}(undef, 1000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could [`mmap`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap/#Mmap.mmap) the file to access it as an array:

```
fd = open("myfile.bin")
y = Mmap.mmap(fd, Vector{Float32}, 10000000)
println(y[3])
```

This will only use virtual memory, but no RAM.  You can also make it writeable, too.